# How to use payment options in an android app.?

Tags: android, payment

Im developing an android application.
The main purpose of this app is to make payments to an industry using various methods like  internet banking, card payments, mobile banking  by the app users to a particular bank account of the industry.

I dont know what kind of tool to use for this app.
Somebody please help me to fix this 
Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put; you can't. You always have to link to another app. For instance, where I'm from we use iDeal to pay with our bank account, but I always need the app from my bank to actually perform the payment. I guess it's the same for other banks in other countries. You can't just integrate it in your app due to security issues. Also, these kind of questions are terrible, since they will only lead to discussions; you aren't asking for a solution to a particular problem, you are asking "how do I do this", which isn't permitted on SO.